# Identifying and Combining multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to write a macro which will select all values the same in one column, move across two columns then combine all the data in those cells into one. Then I need it to repeat until everything is combined.

```
1     122
1     121
2     351
3     351
3     352
4     176
9.1   350
10    351
10    352
```

If this is our raw data, I need to select all the values of 1 in the first column, offset my selection two columns, then combine those cells into one. I then need to run the duplicate function on column A to remove all the spare cells and give a straight list. I'm hoping it can look like this:

```
1     122, 121
2     351
3     351, 352
4     176
9.1   350
10    351, 352
```

The kicker is that this needs to happen for an unknown number of times for an unknown number of values in both column A (as we have a varying number of groups) and column B (as each group has a varying number of values in it.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thank you,

Allan Ramsay

Comment: Have you attempted any code yet? Please post it if you have.

Comment: Hey Allan -- naturally I don't know where this sits in your business process, but if you're not passing this "re-coded" information to a different program you may want to check out a built-in functionality of Excel called pivot tables. A pivot table would help you visualize your data in this way by categorizing your rows: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-create-a-pivottable-report-HA010359471.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it has separate input and output sheets:

```
Sub RePackage()
    Dim N As Long, K As Long, i As Long
    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    s2.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    s2.Cells(1, 1).Value = s1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    s2.Cells(1, 2).Value = s1.Cells(1, 2).Text
    v = s1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    K = 1
    For i = 2 To N
        If s1.Cells(i, 1).Value = v Then
            s2.Cells(K, 2).Value = s2.Cells(K, 2).Text & "," & s1.Cells(i, 2).Text
        Else
            K = K + 1
            s2.Cells(K, 1).Value = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
            s2.Cells(K, 2).Value = s1.Cells(i, 2).Text
            v = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```